# Adding BUs to Corporate Edition (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, child-to-parent, sfmc-business-unit

Client has been using a Corporate edition of Marketing Cloud and acquired a new separate business... so, we need to add a BU to Corporate Edition.

Do we need to add 1 business unit or 2?  Support says two, but if we're merely adding a new business unit - and it doesn't require being "connected" to the data in the parent BU - why do we need two BUs?

Any guidance would be appreciated here.

Comment: I would suggest to it is always better to **talk to your Account Executive**, who can Not only better guide you, they also provide information about potential hidden-COST involved!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to consider with your business unit set up such as using the connector to synchronize data between SalesCloud/Service Cloud and if you will need a Multi-Org setup.

Support may be recommending an additional 2 child business units (BU) as it is good practice to keep the parent business unit as the top-level admin BU — especially if you need to keep subscriber data separate in your child level BU. For instance, if you want only subscribers who opt out of Child BU 1 to only opt out of that BU and not affect subscribers in Child BU 2, then you will need 2 additional BUs.

Also keep in mind that the All Subscribers list on your parent BU will hold all subscribers in your Child BUs. Therefore, it would be extremely difficult to keep the data separate in just 1 parent BU and 1 child BU.

Comment: To Jackson's point: it's really dependent on how the business views this additional BU.  Is it an entirely separate brand, or does it have an element of sharing needs (content, data, subscriber, etc.)

Comment: Note that content and data extensions can be shared across BUs with shared folders, but separate subscriber opt-ins are difficult to manage if one of the BU is a parent BU.